# Getting an empty LogLogPlot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Consider

```
s[t_] := Exp[-t^2] Sin[5 t]
sf[w_, n_] = FourierTransform[Exp[-t^2] Sin[n t], t, w];
```

Then

```
Table[Plot[Abs[sf[w, n]], {w, 1, 15}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], {n, {1, 5, 10}}]
```

[image]

but when I

```
Table[LogLogPlot[Abs[sf[w, n]], {w, 1, 15}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], {n, {1, 5, 10}}]
```

[image]
the last plot remains empty.

(note that `WorkingPrecision -> 100` is near the minimum amount for which `sf` gets plotted correctly with `Plot`; increasing it won't solve the problem with the last plot)

This has happened to me also in other situations, with different functions.

I wonder

1. What is happening in the last and other similar plots
2. How can I handle this situation, not on this particular case but in general

**Version: 11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)**

Comment: Are you sure? Mathematica 10.4 returns this https://imgur.com/a/0BElEyM

Comment: Yes, the plots are correct. I think it is something related to the newer version

Answer (score 1):

Use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) when defining functions in Mathematica. It's better practice:

```
s[t_] := Exp[-t^2] Sin[5 t]
sf[w_, n_] := FourierTransform[Exp[-t^2] Sin[n t], t, w];

Table[Plot[Abs[sf[w, n]], {w, 1, 15}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 100], {n, {1, 5, 10}}]

Table[LogLogPlot[Abs[sf[w, n]], {w, 1, 15}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 100], {n, {1, 5, 10}}]
```

[image]

Comment: What is the rationale behind this behaviour? I mean, how can the results be different? I understand the difference between = and := but I didn't think it could make such a difference

Comment: Also, this was to me the typical case in which using = would be preferred over := since the symbolic calculation of the transform is a bit slow (as in http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node381.html)